# presentModalViewController gives a black screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

In an alert view method I implemented the following (pretty standard) piece of code for popping a modal view:

```
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        EmergencyPlanViewController *emergencyPlanView = [[[EmergencyPlanViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        [emergencyPlanView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
        [self presentModalViewController:emergencyPlanView animated:YES];
    }
```

Somehow it gives me a black screen as result. I can't find what is wrong here.
I created the window in my MainStoryBoard and customized the class of the viewcontroller in IB   to EmergencyPlanViewController.

The viewDidLoad method of the emergencyPlanView is triggered but it looks like the view is not loaded. Anyone an idea what's wrong here?

**EDIT:**
To be clear, I am not using seperate xib-files in my project. I only use the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

In the `xib` file, is your `UIView` set to the File Owner's view. That is probably the problem. Also if you just apply `init`, that will load the `EmergencyPlanViewController`interface builder file with the same name:
 `EmergencyPlanViewController.xib`
So make sure in that case that either:
The `EmergencyPlanViewController` nib is indeed:  `EmergencyPlanViewController.xib`
or that you write instead of `init`: `initWithNibName://whatever nib name here`

Comment: Ok, but I don't use any xib-files but created a seperate viewcontroller on my storyboard. Should it has something to do with this maybe?

Comment: It has something to do with your storyboard in that case

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the black screen issue when presenting a modal view controller by setting a background color to the view in Interface Builder. I noticed that by default the background color of the view is set to something like black/white (see picture attached), although it appears in white. I don't know exactly what does this mean or how it is responsible for showing a black screen, but setting a single color or texture fixed it. PS: I've faced this when migrating from iOS SDK 5 to 6.

[image: Interface Builder Snapshot]

[ios6](/questions/tagged/ios6)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
    EmergencyPlanViewController *emergencyPlanView=[[EmergencyPlanViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EmergencyPlanViewController" bundle:nil];
    emergencyPlanView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:emergencyPlanView animated:YES];
```